# How to force <img> to show image even if status of response is 404?

Tags: php, html, http, http-headers, httprequest

I wrote a class that automatically creates pictures' previews. It works like this: Somewhere in the code of our major application we write

```
<img src="<?= Thumbnail::link('/image/uploads/1234567.png', 400, 300, Thumbnal::MODE_CROP) ?>">
```

And a link  is created which will return thumbnail with width no more than 400 and height no more than `300px`.

This static method `link()` which you can see above, is doing nothing but create a link to the thumbnail. But at that point there is no thumbnail yet. If it is just a common link tag like this

```
<a href="<?= Thumbnail::link('/image/uploads/1234567.png', 400, 300, Thumbnal::MODE_CROP) ?>">
```

what happens when we click on it is:
1.We go to not existant URL and as expected we get 404. But in .htacces I got this line:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /Thumbnail-resize.php
```

Which makes Thumbnail-resize.php as 404 hanlder. What it is doing is basically

```
$brandNewPic = Thumbnail::resize($src, $newWidth, $newHeight, $mode);
} catch (Exception $e) {
   echo $e->getTraceAsString();
}
Thumbnail::sendHeader(Thumbnail::$type);
readfile($brandNewPic);
```

Creates thumbnail by static method `Thumbnail::resize()`
and shows created picture. This strategy was chosen in order to assure that generating of  thumbnails occurred only once,
and if server already has this requested thumbnail we just gave a link on it.

So we won't need to run this slow php script again.
It works perfectly neat when I use it like I shown above with tag `<a>` and clicking on it and picture appearing in browser eventually.

But when I try to show thumbnail directly on the page in `<img>` tag, I fail, because apparently browser won't show an image if it gets 404 in response status. Although my thumbnail-generating script **is triggered and thumbnail is created (moreover i get the picture in the response body)**, but all I see is alternative text. If I refresh the page, picture appears however. But I need it to be shown immediately whithout additional refreshing. What can you suggest?

[image: firebug observation]

Comment: can you do `file_exists($brandNewPic)` before `readfile($brandNewPic)`? If yes then add a default image on readfile().

Comment: I am sorry, but I'm afraid I don't quite understand you, could you please be a little more specific?

Comment: i am saying to use a `if` before `readfile` with condition `file_exists($brandNewPic)` and in `else` get a default image. also any exception thrown in echo $e->getTraceAsString()?

Comment: @GunnerAziz no, no exceptions.

Comment: then you have to write that if else i'm afraid. But I cant test the full code without your Thumbnail-resize.php

Comment: @GunnerAziz I don't get it what do you mean by default image. Please take a look [GitHub]:https://github.com/dKab/myPreview

Comment: default image means what do you want to show if there is no image